# In Sitecore 8, Issue While Rebuild search indexes,Rebuild link database and Indexing manager

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am novice with Sitecore, before publishing my VS solution, while I do rebuild search indexin,the link database and run Indexing manager for all the indexes I get message like Rebuilding Processed 0 items, and it goes for endless time. can any one suggest me why I am getting this each time? and how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Did you check your log files for errors?

Comment: Can you check /sitecore/admin/Jobs.aspx to make sure that any other job is currently running and blocking progress?

Comment: @Bartlomiej Mucha , I don't find jobs.aspx inside admin folder i.e MyProject\sandbox\Website\sitecore\admin

Answer (score 0):

Ranjith, this typically happens when it is queued. Sitecore is probably doing something at that time. Please use the following tool https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/ExperienceContentManagementAdministration.aspx to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The jobs.aspx page is not in built in Sitecore installation. You can check this [post](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2014/11/11/sitecore-job-viewer-see-what-sitecore-is-doing-behind-your-back/) on how to setup the jobs.aspx page. It is just a copy paste in the admin folder.

There are different reasons why the processed item result might be 0:

1. Is the index configuration file correct.
2. Are there any items in the path being crawled.
3. Are the crawlers correct. The crawler type should be `<crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">`
4. If you are using lucene, the configuration type should be `<configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">`